# How to prevent deallocated objects in GCD?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatchworkitem

This function is supposed to re-schedule the execution of a work item:

```
class MyClass {

    var id: String?
    var workItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    var isDoing = false

    func myFunction() {

        guard let id = self.id else { return }

        isDoing = true
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["id": id])
        workItem?.cancel()

        workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
            self.isDoing = false
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: MyNotification, object: nil, userInfo: ["id": id])
        }

        if let workItem = workItem { 
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + DispatchTimeInterval.seconds(10), execute: workItem)
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine in development, but the design seems suspicious, so I ask some  basic questions:

1. Could `workItem` be nil, if  `workItem?.cancel()` is called just before the queue tries to execute the `workItem`?
2. Could `id` inside `workItem` ever be nil when `workItem` is executed or is it retained by the scoped `let id = self.id`?
3. Could `isDoing` inside `workItem` be already deallocated when the `workItem` is executed if the `MyClass` object has been deallocated? In other words, what happens to the scheduled `workItem` when the `MyClass` object is deallocated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not sure what you mean. You don't nil out `workItem` anywhere.
2. No, it can't be `nil` since you're working with a local variable - a copy of `self.id`. By using `guard` you make sure that local variable `id` is not nil, and closure keeps a strong reference (by default) to captured values, so it won't be deallocated.
3. `isDoing` is an instance variable of `MyClass` so it can't be deallocated before `MyClass` instance is deallocated. The problem is, in your case `MyClass` can't be deallocated because you're looking at a strong reference cycle. The closure, by default, keeps a strong reference to the value captured, and you are capturing `self`. And since `self` keeps a strong reference to `workItem`, which in turn keeps a strong reference to closure that captures `self`, hence the reference cycle.

In general, when capturing `self` you use a capture list to work with a weak reference to `self` and do a check whether it hasn't been deallocated

```
workItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    // do stuff with strongSelf
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the strong reference cycle. Would `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:t, execute:{ ... })` also need a weak reference to self in the closure to prevent a strong reference cycle? I would assume not, because it isn't a variable of the class which just means that the class won't be deallocated before the block is executed, correct?

Comment: Since the closure in `asyncAfter` is `@escaping`, it needs to be retained by dispatch queue, so yes, you'd need a weak reference to `self` as well.